# jQuery Slideout Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, user-interface

I am trying to think of a way that the tabs on the left (that currently slide out to the right and the content of which is hidden by the window... see picture http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/7269/ololololo.gif ) can slide out from the black area - which will change depending on the size of the window (as the content is centrally aligned)... I was thinking of using a div to cover the black bit that resizes depending on the size of the window but that seems really complicated... surely there is an easier way to achieve this effect?

If it helps at all, i am making this in a Theme for Drupal 6...
Thanks,
Josh

Comment: There's probably a jQuery plugin that does what you want. That's going to be the "easy way."

Comment: there is a jquery plugin for sliding out, yeh, but it goes from the left/right/top/bottom of the page, not the top/left/right/bottom of a div

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tab-slide-out), it seems to do what you need.

> Create a side tab that expands content for a feedback form or contact info. Make your own image to use as a tab and apply this plugin to any div to hide the content off the right, left, top or bottom of the screen, It animates to show the content, when the handle/tab is clicked.

Comment: There is a plugin, what could be a easier way to achieve that ? (or there is something I miss...)

Comment: I think you missed that it shouldn't come out of the side of the page, it should come out of the side of the centered div (big grey bit in the image).